# SSRS LookupSet returns only one kind of value

Tags: reporting-services

I'm designing a report in Report Builder 3.0.
Here is my [sample dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/450bd/1).

The column `Event_ActivityName` contains two distinct values.
I'm trying to get a comma seperated list of all values from this column using `LookupSet` with this expression:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Event_ActivityName.Value, Fields!Event_ActivityName.Value, Fields!Event_ActivityName.Value, "Main"),",")
```

(Where `Main` is the name of the dataset in Report Builder).

Unfortunately, the result of this expression is a comma seperated list of the value which shows first in the column times the number of times it appears in the column. 

In other words, my column contains two distinct values, but my expression only returns one of them. How do I make it return both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LookupSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) compares a source expression to a destination expression, then returns a result expression when they match.  In this case, you are asking `LookupSet` to find  the Event_ActivityName in scope and bring back all instances of it (which is why you only get back one value times the number of occurrences in the set).

To get all values from this column, use source and destination expressions that will always be equal, like:

```
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!Event_ActivityName.Value, "Main"),",")
```

Comment: Thanks @stubaker. I've read all about `LookupSet`, but I still don't really get it. The source expression is a reference to a field in my dataset ("Main"). I though this means `LookupSet` will go through all records in that field, and whenever the destination expression **of that record (=row)** matches, it will bring back the result expression.

Comment: Another way you can think about `LookupSet` is as a `LEFT JOIN` between two datasets.  In the original case joining Main to Main `ON Event_ActivityName = Event_ActivityName` would get, for each row in Main, all rows/values matching that activity.  I'm not sure if that's any clearer, but I think about it this way sometimes.